# Python Modules listed in help differ from what pip is finding

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, pythonpath

I am having a bit of trouble getting my code to find a my beautifulsoup4 module.
When listing the modules I have installed, python gives the list that I have supplied below (no mention of beatifulsoup4 or bs4)

But, when I run the pip install for the module I get the output which can be seen below

If anyone could explain this discrepancy and/or supply the code necessary for my file to find this module that would be great.

(If it is helpful: my code is in Home/username/Desktop/mycode and my module is installed in Home/username/Desktop/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Modules:

```
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

BaseHTTPServer      asynchat            imaplib             sha
Bastion             asyncore            imghdr              shelve
CDROM               atexit              imp                 shlex
CGIHTTPServer       audiodev            importlib           shutil
Canvas              audioop             imputil             signal
ConfigParser        base64              inspect             site
Cookie              bdb                 io                  smtpd
DLFCN               binascii            itertools           smtplib
Dialog              binhex              json                sndhdr
DocXMLRPCServer     bisect              keyword             socket
FileDialog          bsddb               lib2to3             spwd
FixTk               bz2                 linecache           sqlite3
HTMLParser          cPickle             linuxaudiodev       sre
IN                  cProfile            locale              sre_compile
MimeWriter          cStringIO           logging             sre_constants
Queue               calendar            macpath             sre_parse
ScrolledText        cgi                 macurl2path         ssl
SimpleDialog        cgitb               mailbox             stat
SimpleHTTPServer    chunk               mailcap             statvfs
SimpleXMLRPCServer  cmath               markupbase          string
SocketServer        cmd                 marshal             stringold
StringIO            code                math                stringprep
TYPES               codecs              md5                 strop
Tix                 codeop              mhlib               struct
Tkconstants         collections         mimetools           subprocess
Tkdnd               colorsys            mimetypes           sunau
Tkinter             commands            mimify              sunaudio
UserDict            compileall          mmap                symbol
UserList            compiler            modulefinder        symtable
UserString          contextlib          multifile           sys
_LWPCookieJar       cookielib           multiprocessing     sysconfig
_MozillaCookieJar   copy                mutex               syslog
__builtin__         copy_reg            netrc               tabnanny
__future__          crypt               new                 tarfile
_abcoll             csv                 nis                 telnetlib
_ast                ctypes              nntplib             tempfile
_bisect             curses              ntpath              termios
_codecs             datetime            nturl2path          test
_codecs_cn          dbhash              numbers             textwrap
_codecs_hk          dbm                 opcode              this
_codecs_iso2022     decimal             operator            thread
_codecs_jp          difflib             optparse            threading
_codecs_kr          dircache            os                  time
_codecs_tw          dis                 os2emxpath          timeit
_collections        distutils           ossaudiodev         tkColorChooser
_csv                dl                  parser              tkCommonDialog
_ctypes             doctest             pdb                 tkFileDialog
_ctypes_test        dumbdbm             pickle              tkFont
_elementtree        dummy_thread        pickletools         tkMessageBox
_functools          dummy_threading     pipes               tkSimpleDialog
_hashlib            email               pkgutil             toaiff
_heapq              encodings           platform            token
_hotshot            errno               plistlib            tokenize
_io                 exceptions          popen2              trace
_json               fcntl               poplib              traceback
_locale             filecmp             posix               ttk
_lsprof             fileinput           posixfile           tty
_multibytecodec     fnmatch             posixpath           turtle
_multiprocessing    formatter           pprint              types
_osx_support        fpformat            profile             unicodedata
_pyio               fractions           pstats              unittest
_random             ftplib              pty                 urllib
_socket             functools           pwd                 urllib2
_sqlite3            future_builtins     py_compile          urlparse
_sre                gc                  pyclbr              user
_ssl                gdbm                pydoc               uu
_strptime           genericpath         pydoc_data          uuid
_struct             getopt              pyexpat             warnings
_symtable           getpass             quopri              wave
_sysconfigdata      gettext             random              weakref
_testcapi           glob                re                  webbrowser
_threading_local    grp                 readline            whichdb
_tkinter            gzip                repr                wsgiref
_warnings           hashlib             resource            xdrlib
_weakref            heapq               rexec               xml
_weakrefset         hmac                rfc822              xmllib
abc                 hotshot             rlcompleter         xmlrpclib
aifc                htmlentitydefs      robotparser         xxsubtype
antigravity         htmllib             runpy               zipfile
anydbm              httplib             sched               zipimport
argparse            idlelib             select              zlib
array               ihooks              sets                
ast                 imageop             sgmllib
```

If this is helpful, my PYTHONPATH is:

```
['/home/username/Desktop/mycode', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

This was found by running this program:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that beautifulsoup is installed into a directory that is not on your PYTHONPATH.  Try this temporary solution:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
help('modules')
```

You should now see bs4 listed, and usable.  Keep in mind that this is not a permanent solution--you will need to add the directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable, or install beautifulsoup in a directory that is already on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: When doing this I get the following: `>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
>>> help('modules')

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Then, when I run it again the same output occurs as if nothing was done in the beginning.

Comment: Listing modules from `help` has the side-effect of importing every available module in order to read docstrings.  A segmentation fault could occur for many reasons after changing the PYTHONPATH, and may or may not indicate an issue with the module you are interested in.  Have you tried appending `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to your PYTHONPATH, as above, and then running your code to see if it behaves any differently?

Comment: Adding that line to the top of my program work (after import sys). Thank you.